# SQL Server and xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I will pass this xml as a `varchar` to a scalar function in SQL Server:

```
<ScreenerInfo>
    <ExtendExpiryInfo>
        <ExtendExpiry>
            <ActionOn>2015-05-19 13:31:40.019</ActionOn>
            <Comments>nikilesh</Comments>
            <ApprovalStatus>EE</ApprovalStatus>
            <NewExpiryDate>2015/06/25 12:28:59PM</NewExpiryDate>
        </ExtendExpiry>
    </ExtendExpiryInfo>
</ScreenerInfo>
```

I want to retrieve every thing between the comment tag and separate each comment with a comma store it in `varchar` variable and return it how can I achieve this......

for eg...

```
nikilesh,manish,done,rejected...
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Where is the comment tag? Whar are comments?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, of what relevance is the fact that you stored the string in a `varchar` or at a SQL server?

Comment: [tag:sql-server] and [tag:xml] - two great *tags* to apply to your question. As the entirety of your question *title*, not so much. Opinion here is that tags don't belong in titles - but if we remove them here, we're left with *nothing*.

Comment: If it's an XML - why are you using `varchar` and why not `XML` as datatype??

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, where your "manish" or "done" or "rejected" comes from, but as you are asking for the content of the Comments-node only I'd assume, that there are more nodes with these phrases in Comments-node. In the following example I copied your example node three times and changed the content of the Comments. If you paste this into an empty query window you'll get:

```
Result: nikilesh, manish, done

DECLARE @xml XML=
'<Root>
  <ScreenerInfo>
    <ExtendExpiryInfo>
        <ExtendExpiry>
            <ActionOn>2015-05-19 13:31:40.019</ActionOn>
            <Comments>nikilesh</Comments>
            <ApprovalStatus>EE</ApprovalStatus>
            <NewExpiryDate>2015/06/25 12:28:59PM</NewExpiryDate>
        </ExtendExpiry>
    </ExtendExpiryInfo>
  </ScreenerInfo>
  <ScreenerInfo>
    <ExtendExpiryInfo>
        <ExtendExpiry>
            <ActionOn>2015-05-19 13:31:40.019</ActionOn>
            <Comments>manish</Comments>
            <ApprovalStatus>EE</ApprovalStatus>
            <NewExpiryDate>2015/06/25 12:28:59PM</NewExpiryDate>
        </ExtendExpiry>
    </ExtendExpiryInfo>
  </ScreenerInfo>
  <ScreenerInfo>
    <ExtendExpiryInfo>
        <ExtendExpiry>
            <ActionOn>2015-05-19 13:31:40.019</ActionOn>
            <Comments>done</Comments>
            <ApprovalStatus>EE</ApprovalStatus>
            <NewExpiryDate>2015/06/25 12:28:59PM</NewExpiryDate>
        </ExtendExpiry>
    </ExtendExpiryInfo>
  </ScreenerInfo>
</Root>';


SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT ', ' + Screener.Info.value('(ExtendExpiryInfo/ExtendExpiry/Comments)[1]','varchar(max)')
    FROM @xml.nodes('/Root/ScreenerInfo') AS Screener(Info)
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1,2,'')
```

If you need something else, please clearify your question...

Answer (score 0):

Up-to my understanding i made this.
Even-though it's very bad practice i just did for what you asked.

Function can be written as follows

```
CREATE FUNCTION xml_update 
(
    @XML xml
)
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @output VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @output = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + tab.col.value('(Comments)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
                     FROM @xml.nodes('/ScreenerInfo/ExtendExpiryInfo/ExtendExpiry') AS tab(col) FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'')
RETURN @output
END
GO
```

> Now you can get the expected output.

```
DECLARE @XML xml = '<ScreenerInfo>
                    <ExtendExpiryInfo>

                        <ExtendExpiry>
                            <ActionOn>2015-05-19 13:31:40.019</ActionOn>
                            <Comments>nikilesh</Comments>
                            <ApprovalStatus>EE</ApprovalStatus>
                            <NewExpiryDate>2015/06/25 12:28:59PM</NewExpiryDate>
                        </ExtendExpiry>
                        <ExtendExpiry>
                            <ActionOn>2015-05-19 13:31:40.019</ActionOn>
                            <Comments>manish</Comments>
                            <ApprovalStatus>EE</ApprovalStatus>
                            <NewExpiryDate>2015/06/25 12:28:59PM</NewExpiryDate>
                        </ExtendExpiry>
                        <ExtendExpiry>
                            <ActionOn>2015-05-19 13:31:40.019</ActionOn>
                            <Comments>ragul</Comments>
                            <ApprovalStatus>EE</ApprovalStatus>
                            <NewExpiryDate>2015/06/25 12:28:59PM</NewExpiryDate>
                        </ExtendExpiry>
                    </ExtendExpiryInfo>
                </ScreenerInfo>'

select dbo.xml_update(@XML)
```

Let me know if you need further clarification.